# JSF: ordered list and inplace editing

Tags: jsf

We are using JSF and I was looking for a component to implement a list that:

- can be re-ordered (buttons/drag and drop/whatever)
- elements can be added and deleted
- elements can be edited

To be more explicit something like [PrimeFaces `OrderList`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/orderList.jsf) where elements can be edited. *inplace* editing would be nice but not a requirement. Before implementing something that already exists I wanted to ask if I missed something and the component already exists.

Comment: what's the JSF version your working with, 1.x or 2.x?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at Richfaces and IceFaces in addition to PrimeFaces. They all provide advanced components that might offer almost all the features you need.

Comment: I checked, the closest is still the OrderList of PrimeFaces. As far as I can see nor Richfaces or IceFaces offer something similar.